# Turn list of dask Series into a dask DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, boolean, dask, series

I have a list that contains several **dask Series**. Each Series is boolean and has the same length. Here is an extract of three elements, just to show them.

```
[Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=15
    bool
     ...
    ... 
     ...
     ...
Name: Sequence, dtype: bool
Dask Name: eq, 75 tasks, Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=15
    bool
     ...
    ... 
     ...
     ...
Name: Sequence, dtype: bool
Dask Name: eq, 75 tasks, Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=15
    bool
     ...
    ... 
     ...
     ...
Name: Sequence, dtype: bool
Dask Name: eq, 75 tasks]
```

I turn this list into a **dask DataFrame**, whereby each series will represent a different **column**. I do so with `dd.concat(List_of_series, axis=1, interleave_partitions=True)`.

The command works, but I get the following `UserWarning`:

```
/home/schmat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py:1056: UserWarning: Concatenating dataframes with unknown divisions.
We're assuming that the indexes of each dataframes are 
 aligned. This assumption is not generally safe.
  "Concatenating dataframes with unknown divisions.\n"
```

How can I get rid of this warning? The resulting concatenation is exactly what I want, when I `compute()` it.

Comment: Any solution? I might find this useful

Comment: Nope, still there.

Comment: Such a shame, any help from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the warning, you can use `ignore_unknown_divisions=True`

For more info, check the documentation:
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.multi.concat.html